# How do I find daily expected portfolio return that has both short and long assets?

Tags: finance, portfolio

For example, let's say we have 3 assets (A, B, C) with weights (0.3, 0.3, -0.4). Hence the portfolio is 20% net long.

Assets have daily price returns of [[0.01, -0.02], [0.03, 0.04], [-0.01, 0.03]].
i.e) On day 1, A has 1% return and on Day 2, B has 4% return.

I know I can calculate day 1 portfolio return by: (0.1)(0.3) + (0.03)(0.3) + (-0.01)(-0.4) = 0.043

How can I calculate day 2 portfolio return against previous day's balance?